# How to get two different textbox values and store in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have 40 textbox code is below

```
<asp:textbox ID="txtemail" runat="server" Cssclass="form-control">
<asp:textbox ID="txtname" runat="server"  Cssclass="name">
<asp:textbox ID="txtemail2" runat="server"  Cssclass="form-control">
<asp:textbox ID="txtname2" runat ="server"  Cssclass="name">
```

like I have 40 textbox 20 for email and 20 for name.I need to store those values into database for that I am using below code

```
foreach (var textbox in panelemail.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        string emailtxt = textbox.Text;
        BAL_F2290 objbalemail = new BAL_F2290();
        Form2290.Form objemail = new Form2290.Form();
        objemail.UserID = Convert.ToString(Session["USER_KEY"]);
        objemail.Email = txtemail.text;
        objemail.name = txtname.text;
        string res = objbalemail.Referral_Email_BAL(objemail);
    }
```

my problem is only one value can pass either email or name but I need to Pass two values at a time. How to pass two values at one loop.

Comment: have you ever worked with custom controls?

Comment: no this is first time i am working ...........

Comment: you can define a user control with two controls inside: name and mail, then when you get the list of Controls.OfType<your_control>, you can easily access to both fields.

Answer (score 0):

The full solution would be to change your view model in order to have a logical group of the name and email textboxes. If you need a quick fix for grouping each two consecutive elements in an enumeration, see the following code:

```
var elements = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(elements.Count() % 2 == 0);
var oddElements = elements.Where((elem, index) => index % 2 == 0);
var evenElements = elements.Where((elem, index) => index % 2 == 1);
var pairs = oddElements.Zip(evenElements, (first, second) => new { first, second });

foreach (var item in pairs)
{
    DoSomething(item.first, item.second);
}
```

You would replace the `elements` with your control collection and `DoSomething` with your logic for whatever you plan to do with name and email.

Answer (score 0):

First rename the initial TextBoxes Name like this

```
<asp:textbox ID="txtemail1" runat="server" Cssclass="form-control">
                     ----^
<asp:textbox ID="txtname1" runat="server"  Cssclass="name">
                    ----^
```

Like wise do for other TextBoxes as well.
After that perform iteration operation to find controls within the `panelemail` control as describe below.

```
for(int i=1;i <= 20;i++) 
{
    //Find the control using ID of Textbox and value of i
    TextBox emailTxt = panelemail.FindControl("txtemail"+i) AS TextBox;
    TextBox nameTxt = panelemail.FindControl("txtname"+i) AS TextBox;  

    string emailValue = String.Empty;
    if(emailTxt !=null)
    emailValue = emailTxt.Text;

    string nameValue = String.Empty;
    if(nameTxt !=null)
    nameValue = nameTxt.Text;

    BAL_F2290 objbalemail = new BAL_F2290();
    Form2290.Form objemail = new Form2290.Form();
    objemail.UserID = Convert.ToString(Session["USER_KEY"]);
    objemail.Email = emailValue;
    objemail.name = nameValue ;
    string res = objbalemail.Referral_Email_BAL(objemail);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving answer..... but we should avoid  20 times calling database. Only one time we should call database.